# aws deploy nodejs express backend served HTML file but unable to load react js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a React frontend app with nodejs express backend I have deployed on AWS EC2 instance. Currently it is only serving the html file but not loading the js file correctly (it works correctly locally). I've looked up on stackoverflow and found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622394/nodejs-express-served-html-file-not-loading-js-file) but I was not able to fix it.

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
let app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build')));

// some routes here

// app.get(“*”, (req, res) => {res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: " + port)
})
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

On "/" it looks up the html file from the build folder correctly but it was not able to locate the js files. How should I fix the issue? Thanks!

**Edit**
index.html file, just the basic index.html from create-react-app template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" type='text/javascript'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" type='text/javascript' />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
i
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>Recommender System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have script and link tags in the HTML file?

Comment: @AvivLo please see above update. the html file is just the template file from create-react-app. I think the issue might be after the build it cannot locate js files for some reason. I'm not sure if I'm serving the routes correctly.

Comment: Look at the updated answer. I think I ran into a similar situation before.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build your react app first before running the node backend.

The problem here is that you have `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build')));` points to the `./client/build` directory which does not exist if you start your node backend without having finished building your react app first.

So maybe try building the react app first, and start the node app after that.

> Update:

Because you set the path in express as `./client/build`, you can perhaps add  `./` before the routes, you put in the `src` attribute of your script tags. Like `./static/xx.js`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my package.json for server it has `start: npm run build-client && node server` so it creates the directory. Also it can grab the html which is also in the directory, so `/build` should exist.

Comment: Hmm, strange. So how are you loading those js files?

Comment: In the build folder (after build step) under `/static/js` i can see the js files and it is inserted into the html file as a link. But it isn't loaded correctly, the errors happened in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61329893/nodejs-and-react-app-deployment-on-aws-not-rendering-react-ui)

Comment: I just realized that I was the person answering that question yesterday.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I didn't set the link to the js files, it is added during build process in `build/static` is there any way i can modify the server.js file to serve them differently?

Comment: The `server.js` sets the route here: `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build')));`  I am just asking how does react loads js file when rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212207/discussion-between-zzzzz-2-and-aviv-lo).